# Jquery Dynamic table column issue

Tags: jquery, html, css, forms, datepicker

I have a jquery dynamic table its values comes from the from,to date picker. I need display first two columns free for adding two informations. How can i make it possible. Iam attaching my fiddle here  http://jsfiddle.net/uScc2/9/

```
<table cellpadding="0" cellspacing="1" id="our_table">
    <th id="dte"></th>
    <tr>
    </tr>
    <tr>
    </tr>
</table>
```

Comment: I'm a bit confused about what you're asking for. Do you want two extra columns in the table for the "for" and "to" dates?

Comment: i need two columns extra for  adding category and number. table starting column is category and next column is number

Answer (score 1, accepted):

try this updated fiddle of [yours](http://jsfiddle.net/uScc2/14/)

i simply put these:

```
 $('#our_table tr.td_rows').append('<td>CATEGORY HERE</td>');
 $('#our_table tr.td_rows').append('<td>NUMBER HERE</td>');
```

before looping your data. and these:

```
newHeaders += '<th>COLUMN</th><th>NUMBER</th><th>' + between[i] + '</th>';
```

for the headers

Comment: but some error there. when selecting the date picker range the column repetes